# Why is this listener never called?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm trying to use Riverpod for my project, however I'm hitting some issues.

I am not sure that I'm using it very well so don't hesitate to tell me if you see anything wrong with it :)

First I have my `authProvider`:

```dart
final authRepoProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
   return AuthRepository();
});

class AuthRepository extends ChangeNotifier {
    String? token;

    Future signIn(String username, String password) async {
        // Do the API calls...
        token = tokenReturnedByAPI;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Then I have a service, let's say it allows to fetch blog Articles, with a stream to get live update about those.

```dart
class ArticleService {
    StreamController<Article> _streamCtrl;
    String? _token;
    API _api;

    ArticleService(this._api) : _streamCtrl = StreamController<Article>() {
        _api.onLiveUpdate((liveUpdate) {
            _streamCtrl.add(liveUpdate);
        });
    }

    Stream<Article> get liveUpdates => _streamCtrl.stream;

    Future markArticleAsRead(String id) async {
        await _api.markAsRead(_token, id);
    }
}
```

For that article service I would like to keep the current token up to date, but I don't want to rebuild the entire service every time the token changes as there are listeners and streams being used.

For that I would prefer to listen to the changes and update it myself, like such:

```dart
final articleServiceProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) {
    final service = ArticleService(
        ref.read(apiProvider),
    );
    ref.listen<AuthRepository>(authRepositoryProvider, (previous, next) {
        service._token = next.token;
    }, fireImmediately: true);
    return service;
});
```

That piece of code seems correct to me, however when I authenticate (`authRepository.token` is definitely set) and then try to invoke the `markArticlesAsRead` method I end up with an empty token.

The `ref.listen` is never called, even tho `AuthRepository` called `notifyListeners()`.

I have a feeling that I'm using all that in a wrong way, but I can't really pinpoint what or where.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ref.watch`

```
final articleServiceProvider = Provider.autoDispose((ref) {
    final service = ArticleService(
        ref.read(apiProvider),
    );
    final repo = ref.watch<AuthRepository>(authRepositoryProvider);
    service._token = repo.token;
    return service;
});
```

Comment: But won't that rebuild the whole service?